# reading file contents into dict python

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
...previous file content

[NON-UNIFORM LOADS]
    3 = number of items
Load 1
           0        17.50        20.00   0            0  = Time, Gamma dry, Gamma wet, Temporary, Endtime
    6 = Number of co-ordinates
       0.000        0.000 = X, Y
      20.000        0.000 = X, Y
      40.000        2.000 = X, Y
      80.000        2.000 = X, Y
     100.000        0.000 = X, Y
     120.000        0.000 = X, Y
Compensation load
         200        17.50        20.00   0            0  = Time, Gamma dry, Gamma wet, Temporary, Endtime
   19 = Number of co-ordinates
      20.000        0.000 = X, Y
      20.000        1.198 = X, Y
      25.000        2.763 = X, Y
      30.000        3.785 = X, Y
      35.000        4.617 = X, Y
      40.000        5.324 = X, Y
      45.000        5.418 = X, Y
      50.000        5.454 = X, Y
      55.000        5.467 = X, Y
      60.000        5.471 = X, Y
      65.000        5.467 = X, Y
      70.000        5.454 = X, Y
      75.000        5.418 = X, Y
      80.000        5.324 = X, Y
      85.000        4.617 = X, Y
      90.000        3.785 = X, Y
      95.000        2.763 = X, Y
     100.000        1.198 = X, Y
     100.000        0.000 = X, Y
Compensation load 2
         200        17.50        20.00   0            0  = Time, Gamma dry, Gamma wet, Temporary, Endtime
    3 = Number of co-ordinates
       0.000        0.000 = X, Y
      20.000       10.000 = X, Y
      20.000        0.000 = X, Y
[END OF NON-UNIFORM LOADS]

... subsequent file content
```

I would like to read the information into a `dict as follows:

```
result = {'no items':3, 'Load 1':{X:[0,20,40,80,100,120], Y = [0,0,2,2,0,0]}, 'Compensation Load':{...}, 'Compensation load 2':{...}}
```

Are there any third-party libraries that can help me with this? Otherwise what strategy would you use to approach this? I am first using the `readlines` method on the file object, looping through the lines and using an `if` statement to stop where the line contains `'[NON-UNIFORM LOADS]'` however I'm not sure how to come up with an elegant solution from there....

**EDIT**

To respond to the comment, I am trying stuff like this:

```
with open(file) as fo:
    lines = fo.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if r'[NON-UNIFORM LOADS]' in line:
            results['non_uniform_loads'] = {}
            count = 0
            subline = lines[count]
            while '[' not in subline:
                count=count+1
            """
            results['non_uniform_loads'] = {'X':[], 'Z':[]}
            coordinates_count = int(lines[i+4].strip().split()[0])
            for j in range(coordinates_count):
                X_coord = float(lines[i+5+j].strip().split()[0])
                Z_coord = float(lines[i+5+j].strip().split()[1])
                results['non_uniform_loads']['X'].append(X_coord)
                results['non_uniform_loads']['Z'].append(Z_coord)
            """
```

Comment: Did you **try**?

Comment: yes I did, and I also could probably figure it out. But my brain is mush now so I need someone else to look and give me feedback.

Comment: Can you please share your code, what you tried currently ?

Comment: yes. I have just copied it

Comment: This looks like the kind of abysmal custom file format that some scientists and engineers are prone to burden others with. Is it some known file type for which there already exist libraries? If so, use that. Otherwise you'll have to cobble together some hand-written code for it and the most likely tools to help you in a case like this might regular expressions and a little elbow grease.

Comment: right, so the stuff I cobbled together is what I pasted above.... I'm not yet comfortable with regex to use it for something like this so I didn't use it. Perhaps there is some simple algorithm similar to what I have tried above to read it. Indeed it is from older scientific software...

Comment: It seems to me you're overcomplicating a bit. I think this can be done with a single `for` loop and some clever state management. You don't need to call `readlines()` because you can loop directly over a file object by line like `for idx, line in enumerate(go):`. I think if you haven't learned regular expressions yet now is a good time. A mere hour invested on some basic regexps will make this significantly easier and less error-prone. There are many good online resources for learning regexps these days. I'm not at my computer right now otherwise I would propose something more concrete.

Comment: What about `19 = Number of co-ordinates`?

Comment: this text file is damn near unreadable

Comment: Give me an hour or so and I can write you a full solution. Consider it a favor out of sympathy with having to deal with weird file formats created by scientists :) IMO it's not actually that bad; I already have the solution in my head and just need to test it.

Comment: Will do. Thanks in advance for your help. I also need to learn to better deal with such formats, our  software has a lot of input/output files like this :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.  I ended up not using regular expressions at all in order to keep things simpler. And in fact, the sample of the file I've seen *so far* is not complex-enough to merit it.  It might merit it moreso if other parts of the file can have a more complicated structure.

I also wasn't sure if you're using Python 3 or Python 2, so I tried to write it in such a way that it would work with both:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class ParseLoadsError(Exception):
    """Exception raised for malformatted load files."""

    def __init__(self, lineno, line, message):
        super(ParseLoadsError, self).__init__(lineno, line, message)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'parse error on line {}: {!r}; {}'.format(*self.args)


def parse_loads_file(fileobj):
    """Parse a <whatever> file.

    Currently just returns non-uniform loads.  Parsing other
    file sections is left as an exercise.
    """

    result = {'non_uniform_loads': []}

    line_iterator = ((idx, l.strip()) for idx, l in enumerate(fileobj))
    for lineno, line in line_iterator:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '[NON-UNIFORM LOADS]':
            # Read the enter [NON-UNIFORM LOADS] section
            # We pass it line_iterator so it advances the
            # same iterator while reading
            result['non_uniform_loads'].append(_parse_non_uniform_loads(line_iterator))

    return result


def _parse_variable_map(lineno, line):
    """Parse a single <values> = <varnames> mapping.

    This file format uses a format for mapping one or more values
    to one or more variable names in the format::

        N_1 N_2 N_3 ... N_n = A_1, A_2, A_33, ..., A_n

    Where N_i are always either integers or floating-point values, and 
    A_i is the variable name associated with A_i.  The A_i may contain
    spaces, but whitespace is otherwise irrelevant.

    Of course, if other types of values may occur in other sections of
    the file this may be slightly more complicated.  This also assumes
    these lines are always well-formed.  If not, additional logic may be
    required to handle misshapen variables maps.
    """

    try:
        values, varnames = line.split('=')
        values = (float(v.strip()) for v in values.split())
        varnames = (n.strip() for n in varnames.split(','))
        return dict(zip(varnames, values))
    except ValueError:
        raise
        raise ParseLoadsError(lineno, line,
            "expected format N_1 N_2 ... N_n = A_1, A_2, ..., A_n")


def _parse_non_uniform_loads(lines):
    lineno, line = next(lines)
    # The first line of a non-uniform loads section
    # describes the number of loads
    try:
        n_loads = int(_parse_variable_map(lineno, line)['number of items'])
    except KeyError:
        raise ParseLoadsError(lineno, line, "expected 'N = number of items'")

    # Parse loads returns a load_name/load_data, tuple so this returns
    # a dict mapping load_name to load_data for each load
    loads = dict(_parse_load(lines) for _ in range(n_loads))

    lineno, line = next(lines)
    if line != '[END OF NON-UNIFORM LOADS]':
        raise ParseLoadsError(lineno, line, "expected '[END OF NON-UNIFORM LOADS]'")

    return loads


def _parse_load(lines):
    """Parses a single load section."""

    _, load_name = next(lines)

    # Next there appears some additional metadata about the load
    load_data = _parse_variable_map(*next(lines))

    # Then the number of coordinates
    lineno, line = next(lines)
    try:
        n_coords = int(_parse_variable_map(lineno, line)['Number of co-ordinates'])
    except KeyError:
        raise ParseLoadsError(lineno, line, "expected 'N = Number of co-ordinates'")

    coordinates = defaultdict(list)
    for _ in range(n_coords):
        for c, v in _parse_variable_map(*next(lines)).items():
            coordinates[c].append(v)

    load_data['Coordinates'] = dict(coordinates)
    return load_name, load_data
```

Example usage:

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

example_file = StringIO("""...previous file content

[NON-UNIFORM LOADS]
    3 = number of items
Load 1
           0        17.50        20.00   0            0  = Time, Gamma dry, Gamma wet, Temporary, Endtime
    6 = Number of co-ordinates
       0.000        0.000 = X, Y
      20.000        0.000 = X, Y
      40.000        2.000 = X, Y
      80.000        2.000 = X, Y
     100.000        0.000 = X, Y
     120.000        0.000 = X, Y
Compensation load
         200        17.50        20.00   0            0  = Time, Gamma dry, Gamma wet, Temporary, Endtime
   19 = Number of co-ordinates
      20.000        0.000 = X, Y
      20.000        1.198 = X, Y
      25.000        2.763 = X, Y
      30.000        3.785 = X, Y
      35.000        4.617 = X, Y
      40.000        5.324 = X, Y
      45.000        5.418 = X, Y
      50.000        5.454 = X, Y
      55.000        5.467 = X, Y
      60.000        5.471 = X, Y
      65.000        5.467 = X, Y
      70.000        5.454 = X, Y
      75.000        5.418 = X, Y
      80.000        5.324 = X, Y
      85.000        4.617 = X, Y
      90.000        3.785 = X, Y
      95.000        2.763 = X, Y
     100.000        1.198 = X, Y
     100.000        0.000 = X, Y
Compensation load 2
         200        17.50        20.00   0            0  = Time, Gamma dry, Gamma wet, Temporary, Endtime
    3 = Number of co-ordinates
       0.000        0.000 = X, Y
      20.000       10.000 = X, Y
      20.000        0.000 = X, Y
[END OF NON-UNIFORM LOADS]

... subsequent file content""")

# To use an actual file here you might do something like
# with open(filename) as fobj:
#     parse_loads_file(fobj)

parse_loads_file(example_file)
```

Output:

```
{'non_uniform_loads': [{'Compensation load': {'Coordinates': {'X': [20.0,
      20.0,
      25.0,
      30.0,
      35.0,
      40.0,
      45.0,
      50.0,
      55.0,
      60.0,
      65.0,
      70.0,
      75.0,
      80.0,
      85.0,
      90.0,
      95.0,
      100.0,
      100.0],
     'Y': [0.0,
      1.198,
      2.763,
      3.785,
      4.617,
      5.324,
      5.418,
      5.454,
      5.467,
      5.471,
      5.467,
      5.454,
      5.418,
      5.324,
      4.617,
      3.785,
      2.763,
      1.198,
      0.0]},
    'Endtime': 0.0,
    'Gamma dry': 17.5,
    'Gamma wet': 20.0,
    'Temporary': 0.0,
    'Time': 200.0},
   'Compensation load 2': {'Coordinates': {'X': [0.0, 20.0, 20.0],
     'Y': [0.0, 10.0, 0.0]},
    'Endtime': 0.0,
    'Gamma dry': 17.5,
    'Gamma wet': 20.0,
    'Temporary': 0.0,
    'Time': 200.0},
   'Load 1': {'Coordinates': {'X': [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 80.0, 100.0, 120.0],
     'Y': [0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0]},
    'Endtime': 0.0,
    'Gamma dry': 17.5,
    'Gamma wet': 20.0,
    'Temporary': 0.0,
    'Time': 0.0}}]}
```

I wasn't sure if a single file can contain more than one `[NON-UNIFORM LOADS]` section, so I append the contents of each such section to a list (`{'non_uniform_loads': []`).  But if there is only ever one, then you can do away with the list and just set `result['non_uniform_loads'] = _parse_non_uniform_loads(line_iterator)`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use this approach:

```
s = '200        17.50        20.00   0            0  = Time, Gamma dry, Gamma wet, Temporary, Endtime'
```

1. separate each string by the "=" sign

   s_l = s.split(' = ')
2. split by the ' ' separator

   s1 = [float(a.lstrip()) for a in s_l[0].split('   ') if a != '']

   s2 = [a.lstrip() for a in s_l[1].split(',') if a != '']
3. zip the result list to dict

   target_dict = dict(zip(s2, s1))

the result:

```
target_dict: {'Time': 200.0, 'Gamma dry': 17.5, 'Gamma wet': 20.0, 'Temporary': 0.0, 'Endtime': 0.0}
```

4. combine dicts

Answer (score -1):

Here's a disgusting solution.

```
with open(file) as fo:
    lines = fo.readlines()
    results = {}
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if r'[NON-UNIFORM LOADS]' in line:
            results['non_uniform_loads'] = {}
            #get load names and no_coordinates
            no_coords = []
            load_names = []
            load_names_index = []
            j=1
            line = lines[i+j]
            while '[' not in line:
                j=j+1 
                if 'Number of co-ordinates' in line:
                    no_coords.append(int(line.strip().split()[0]))
                elif str_is_float(line.strip().split()[0])==False:
                    load_names.append(line.strip().replace('\n', ''))
                    load_names_index.append(i+j-1)
                else:
                    pass
                line = lines[i+j]
            for j, load_name_index in enumerate(load_names_index):
                results['non_uniform_loads'][load_names[j]] = {'X':[], 'Z':[]}
                current_no_coords = no_coords[j]
                print current_no_coords
                for k in range(current_no_coords):
                    results['non_uniform_loads'][load_names[j]]['X'].append(float(lines[load_name_index+k+3].strip().split()[0]))
                    results['non_uniform_loads'][load_names[j]]['Z'].append(float(lines[load_name_index+k+3].strip().split()[1]))
```

It does the job, but what a nightmare. If @Iguananaut has a more attractive solution (notably using regex) I will gladly accept over this.

Comment: It's not so bad, but it can be improved with judicious use of subroutines (functions), iterators, and additional higher-level abstractions (see e.g. `_parse_variable_map` in my solution)